# How does Glyph of Smite interact with the Holy Fire of other priests?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

[Glyph of Smite](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42416/glyph-of-smite) gives a 20% increase to Smites cast on targets burning with Holy Fire.

Does this Glyph give its 20% bonus to my Smite when another priest has Holy Fire ticking on the target (and I do not)?

Comment: Although I can't test it, spells rarely interact with other player's affects anymore. Those that do specifically mention it in the tooltip, e.g. [hunter's mark](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1130)

Comment: I can't test it either, hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only the presence of *your* Holy Fire that determines whether or not the glyph's bonus damage applies or not, similar to any number of other symbiotic spells in WoW.

That said though, Holy Fire has a higher damage per cast time than Smite, so there's no reason why you'd ever cast Smite when Holy Fire is off cooldown and its DoT is off, making your question kind of moot.

Some numbers to show you what I mean visually:

[image: Smite vs Holy Fire DPCT Comparison]

Comment: Holy Fire lasts only 7 seconds, so for the 3 seconds while the CD is coming off, the question is still relevant.

Comment: I don't follow. It isn't possible to reapply Holy Fire while its DoT is still up.

Comment: Er oops, misread. Would make for interesting staggered Holy Fire applications if it worked eh?